# how to get an array value into controller as i am getting undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs routing where i have an array of employees in factory and the homecontroller displays those arrays in the view and view to html page (please correct me if my sequence or construction is wrong). I do edit and add employee operation on them . While doing edit operation , as soon as i click on the edit link, it routes to edit.html page  and the view is controlled by EditController. However, i want the text boxes to contain and retain there original values, like empId:1, empName:John, empLocation:Mumbai when in edit.html page, but all the values doesn't come . Please help.

**app.js**

```
  angular.module("Swabhav.Employee",['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

     $routeProvider
     .when('/',{
         controller:"HomeController",
         templateUrl:"home.html"

     })
    .when('/add',{
        controller:"AddController",
        templateUrl:"add.html"
    })

    .when('/home',{
        controller:"HomeController",
        templateUrl:"home.html"
    })

    .when('/edit/:empId',{
        controller:"EditController",
        templateUrl:"edit.html"
    })


   }])
```

## EmployeeService Factory

```
  angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")

  .factory("EmployeeService",["$log",function($log){

    var employees=[{"empId":1,"name":"John","location":"Mumbai"},
                   {"empId":2,"name":"Nikita","location":"Mumbai"},
                   {"empId":3,"name":"Saurab","location":"Pune"},
                    {"empId":4,"name":"Ankita","location":"Bangalore"},
                    {"empId":5,"name":"Harsh","location":"Chennai"},
                    {"empId":6, "name":"Geeta","location":"Vellore"}];

    var obj={};

    obj.displayAll=function(){
            return employees;
       }

     obj.getById = function(Id){
        var employee=[];
         $log.log("emp id = "+ Id)
        angular.forEach(employees,function(value,key){
            if(value.empId==Id){
                $log.log("inside");
                $log.log(employees);
                $log.log(value.location)

 employee.push({empId:value.empId,name:value.name,location:value.location});
            $log.log(employee)

            }
            return (employee);
        })

       }

     obj.addEmployee=function(Id,Name,Location){

         $log.log(employees)
         employees.push({empId:Id,name:Name,location:Location})
         return employees;
     }

     obj.editEmployee=function(employeeId,employeeName,employeeLocation){
       var index;
        for(index=0;index<employees.length;index++){
            if(employees.indexOf(employeeId) != -1){

                $log.log("edit employee = "+ employees[index])

                employees.empId=employeeId;
                employees.name=employeeName;
                employees.location=employeeLocation;

            }

        }
        return employees;
     }
    return obj;

  }])
```

## HomeController

```
   angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")
       .controller("HomeController",
  ["$scope","EmployeeService","$log","$window",function($scope,
        EmployeeService,$log,$window){

   $log.log (EmployeeService.displayAll());   

   $scope.data=EmployeeService.displayAll();


   }])
```

## AddController

```
   angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")
    .controller("AddController",
    ["$scope","EmployeeService","$log","$window",function($scope,
        EmployeeService,$log,$window){

        $scope.add=function(empId,name,location){
            $scope.Id=empId;
            $scope.Name=name;
            $scope.Location=location

     EmployeeService.addEmployee($scope.Id,$scope.Name,$scope.Location);
            $window.location.href = "#/home";
        }
    }])
```

## EditController

```
     angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")
           .controller("EditController",
    ["$scope","EmployeeService","$log","$window","$routeParams",
           function($scope,EmployeeService,$log,$window,$routeParams){

            $scope.employeeData=EmployeeService.displayAll();

            $log.log("$scope.employeeData = "+ $routeParams.empId )
            $scope.empIdvalue = $routeParams.empId;

             $scope.editDisplay=
                 EmployeeService.getById($scope.empIdvalue);


      $log.log("EmployeeService.getById(3)"+EmployeeService.getById(3));

                $scope.edit= function(empId,name,location){
                    $scope.Id=empId;
                    $scope.Name=name;
                    $scope.Location=location

     EmployeeService.editEmployee($scope.Id,$scope.Name,$scope.Location);
                    $window.location.href = "#/home";
                }

            }])
```

**home.html**

```
   <article>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th> Edit </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in data" >

                    <td>{{employee.empId}} </td>
                    <td>{{employee.name}} </td>
                    <td>{{employee.location}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#/edit/{{employee.empId}}">Edit</a>

                 </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <br>
    <a href="#add">Add Employee</a>
    </table>

  </article>
```

**edit.html**

```
 <article>
  <h3>Edit Page</h3>
  <br><br>
   empId:<input type="text" ng-value=empIdvalue ng-model="employeeId">
   empName:<input type="text" ng-value=empNamevalue ng-model="employeeName">
  empLocation:<input type="text" ng-value=empLocationvalue ng-
 model="employeeLocation">
  <button type="button"  ng-
  click="edit(employeeId,employeeName,employeeLocation)">Edit</button>
  </article>
```

**index.html**

```
  <html ng-app="Swabhav.Employee">
  <head>
    <title>Employee</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
    <script 
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
 </script>
</head>
 <body>

     <script src="app.js"></script>
     <section ng-view></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does your console print `$scope.employeeData  ...` ?

Comment: nopes...it prints ==>[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `ng-value`. You can use the `$scope.editDisplay` variable as model. You can change your code like this.

**edit.html**

```
<article>
  <h3>Edit Page</h3>
  <br><br>
   empId:<input type="text" ng-model="editDisplay.empId">
   empName:<input type="text" ng-model="editDisplay.name">
  empLocation:<input type="text" ng-model="editDisplay.location">
  <button type="button"  ng-
  click="edit(editDisplay)">Edit</button>
</article>
```

**EditController**

```
angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")
           .controller("EditController",
    ["$scope","EmployeeService","$log","$window","$routeParams",
           function($scope,EmployeeService,$log,$window,$routeParams){

            $scope.employeeData=EmployeeService.displayAll();

            $log.log("$scope.employeeData = "+ $routeParams.empId )
            $scope.empIdvalue = $routeParams.empId;

             $scope.editDisplay=
                 EmployeeService.getById($scope.empIdvalue);


      $log.log("EmployeeService.getById(3)"+EmployeeService.getById(3));

      $scope.edit= function(editDisplay){   
    EmployeeService.editEmployee(editDisplay.empId,editDisplay.name,editDisplay.location);
                    $window.location.href = "#/home";
                }

  }])
```

Comment: I want the original value to be displayed in the text boxes, therefore i have used ng-value. The reply you answered is not the solution to my question. Thank you anyways!

Comment: @java_jazz The `$scope.editDisplay` variable has the original value and it is used as model in the inputs, this will display these values in the text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change you `editcontroller` like this:

```
angular.module("Swabhav.Employee")
           .controller("EditController",
    ["$scope","EmployeeService","$log","$window","$routeParams",
           function($scope,EmployeeService,$log,$window,$routeParams){
            $scope.param1 = $routeParams.empId;
            $scope.employeeData=EmployeeService.displayAll();
            $scope.empIdvalue = $routeParams.empId;
            $scope.editDisplay=
                 EmployeeService.getById($scope.empIdvalue);
            $scope.param2 = $scope.editDisplay[0]["location"];
            $scope.param3 = $scope.editDisplay[0]["name"];


            $scope.edit= function(empId,name,location){
                    $scope.Id=empId;
                    $scope.Name=name;
                    $scope.Location=location;

                    EmployeeService.editEmployee($scope.Id,$scope.Name,$scope.Location);
                    $window.location.href = "#/home";
                }

            }])
```

`param1` `param2` and `param3`,  will be used in your `ng-model` in `edit.html`.

```
<article>
  <h3>Edit Page</h3>
  <br><br>
   empId:<input type="text" disabled="disabled" ng-model="param1">
   empName:<input type="text" ng-value="editDisplay[0]['name']" ng-model="param2">
  empLocation:<input type="text"  ng-value="editDisplay[0]['location']" ng-model="param3">
  <button type="button"  ng-click="edit(editDisplay[0]['empId'],param2,param3)">Edit</button>

  </article>
  <a href=".">return</a>
```

Another error you have comitted in `getById` function, thinking that `foreach` promises return a value to the container parent function, no it just throws back to the nearer promise, it is rather adviced to use a `filter` selector like this:

```
obj.getById = function(Id){
        return employees.filter(function(value,key){
            if(value.empId==Id)
                 return 1;
            else
                 return 0;
        })

       }
```

Finally there is another substiantial change in `editEmployee` function, you seem to jumble it a whole.

```
obj.editEmployee=function(employeeId,employeeName,employeeLocation){
       var index=employees.map((id)=>id.empId).indexOf(employeeId);
        if(index != -1){

                $log.log("edit employee = "+ employees.map((id)=>id.name)[index])

                employees[index].empId=employeeId;
                employees[index].name=employeeName;
                employees[index].location=employeeLocation;

            }

        return employees;
     }
```

[forked here](https://embed.plnkr.co/FmR9ijEiCZXPQ9GZRFVk/)

Comment: thanks for the help. But  is above piece of code for editEmployee to be copy pasted because it doesn't seem to work. Also , is this a valid syntax for angularjs >>employees.map((id)=>id.empId).indexOf(employeeId);

Comment: it's a valid js, and it's working. I made an online demonstration. @java_jazz